# sencha 7.3.1 export plugin for classic framework not working

Tags: extjs

The example on the sencha website is not working. Does anyone have the same problem?

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.Exporter.html

Comment: It does not work for me either. Art Lando ruined that company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working.  It looks like the docs do not have the exporter plugin available.   [Here is a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3agh)

The error on the docs is: Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: plugin.gridexporter

With fiddle you have to check the exporter checkbox under packages.  The exporter is not part of the standard package.